# Including a Java Object in the payload of a POST request to Camunda's '/rest/process-instance/count' endpoint to filter process instances

Tags: java, enums, camunda, camunda-modeler

For the POST endpoint ‘/rest/process-instance/count’ in Camunda, can I include a Java Object variable defined in my Java code within the payload?

For example, considering a payload structured as follows:

```
{"activityIdIn": \["Task1"\], "variables": \[{"name": "carColor", "operator": "eq", "value": "RED"}\]}
```

Where `RED` is an enum defined in my Java code. The objective is to retrieve all process instances in `Task1` where `carColor` equals `RED`.

Comment: Surely you want to pass `RED.toString()` or `RED.name()`?

Comment: I cannot include RED.toString() or RED.name() in the payload. according to the Camunda documentation, the type should be string, boolean, or number, and not a custom ENUM: https://docs.camunda.org/rest/camunda-bpm-platform/7.21-SNAPSHOT/#tag/Process-Instance/operation/queryProcessInstancesCount

Comment: That is exactly why I suggested it. Both those methods return strings.